# how to resolve the error occurred in .Net SqlClient Data Provider?

Tags: c#

Please any one help me:

I run my application was created in C# for export data source t XML document, I also use try catch method for correct an error of database access (`adapter.Fill(ds)`). The problem is show below.

```
n_org:SELECTs_department.did,s_department.name,s_department.fk_deptFROMs_department

Index #0
Message: Incorrect syntax near ','.
LineNumber: 1
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Procedure:
```

Please give a suggestion or any correct code is ok.

Thanks

Comment: There are no spaces between the query being formed. There should at least be one after SELECT and one before and after FROM!

Comment: Your code looks all run together. Is that how it appears in you actual source file? Error indicates a bad comma in select list....but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` statement is all wrong - no spaces anywhere!

Instead of what you have right now:

```
SELECTs_department.did,s_department.name,s_department.fk_deptFROMs_department
```

use a statement that **has** the necessary spaces - like this:

```
SELECT s_department.did, s_department.name, s_department.fk_dept FROM s_department
```